# Can Gentiles observe Yom kippur?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, yom-kippur

Is a Gentile allowed to do all the Jews do on Yom kippur? Or are there any prohibitions?

Comment: Yom Kippur is not about doing, as such, it's about abstaining from eating, drinking, and various other specific pleasures. Other than praying and repenting. Unless you're asking about the prohibition of gentiles to keep Shabbat - and Yom Kippour has the same work-prohibitions as Shabbat.

Comment: I was about to cite @DannySchoemann's comment regarding Shabbat prohibitions. I'm unaware that fasting, itself is problematic. Saying the same prayers I don't think would be a problem, either. Years ago, when I was in Dimona, Israel, there were a group of Black Hebrews who celebrated Yom Kippur by fasting and prayer. They did drive their cars, so they violated Shabbat rules.